# Django Multiple Checkbox Generation

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I am trying to generate a webpage that shows a list of objects pulled from a database with a certain state. The list of objects should include a checkbox next to each object, so that if the user checks the object and presses submit, the server will change the state of that object. Since the list of objects is generated on the fly, I'm confused on how to properly write a Django form that will create the necessary checkboxes.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **model formset**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

This will generate a series of forms, one for each item in the queryset you give it.

Assuming the state is saved as a field on the model, you make a custom `ModelForm` which only has the state field (if it's a `BooleanField` it'll show as a checkbox by default)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

You can then use this custom form in your model formset:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-form